# For each $ a $ with $ |a| > 1 $, $f^{-1}(a)$ contains exactly one point

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-2| < 1\} $ and let $ f $ be
>   analytic in $ \overline{G} $ except for one simple pole $ z_0 $
>   inside. Suppose that $ |f(z)| = 1$ for all $ z \in \partial G $. Show
>   that for all $ a $ with $ |a| > 1 $, $ f^{-1}(a) $ contains exactly
>   one point.

So $f(z) $ can be written as $ \sum a_n (z-2)^n + \frac{b}{z - z_0} $, but I don't know how to use the fact that $ |f(z)| = 1 $ for all $ z \in \partial G $. How to solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is complex analysis, $ |f(z)| = 1 $ on $ \partial G $ should be interpreted in one of two different ways :

- For the maximum modulus principle, however this result doesn't help at all with finding only one preimage of $ a $.
- For the indices of points relative to some curves : here, we get by setting the usual curve $ \gamma : t \mapsto e^{2i \pi t} + 2 $ that $ n(f \circ \gamma, a) = 0 $ because $ \operatorname{Im} f \circ \gamma \subset D_c(0, 1)$ and $ a \not \in D_c(0, 1)$. Thus , we can use the argument principle :

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z) - a}dz = 2 i \pi (\sum n(\gamma, \text{zero of } f(z) - a) - \sum n(\gamma, \text{pole of } f(z) - a))$$

and notice that $ \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z) - a}dz = n(f\circ \gamma, a) = 0$. The result then follows.

Comment: So for this problem, $ |f(z) | \leq 1 $ on $ \partial G $ is enough since the winding number is still $ 0 $ in this case, correct?

Comment: @lifeishard911 I do think that is the case.